# How to query Firebase nodes containing Arrays

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Database Structure for my chat application like this:

[image: database structure]

The `member` node contains the list of userid. I want to make a query with the userid and get the all the data wrt to the trash which contain that userid within its member node.

Say for example: If I query with userid `"Ar9emr50ZRhWewpl7jKtJ9Bwr2s2"`, I should get all the data from trash with id `"-KuLIYP8IQJTCz62o9UU"` and `"-KuLZatX9_gK_v81EhVJ"`.

I tried with indexing the `member` but it supports only to query for single element values not for the list of values.

Comment: You may need to create another node for users to store their trash ids . example : user_trash/{user_id}/trash/{trash_code} = 1

Comment: Thanks @agit for the reply. I understand that but my ideal goal using the queries here is to get the "chatname" and "group_prof_pic". By your method, I will get only trash ids but not the other details.

Comment: Actually after you get trash ids , you can use them get details for each trash . But I think, you already do not want to do such an extra query.

Comment: @agit: I think you have all the parts of a great answer here. :-) If you think OP may worry about performance of loading the details, I always refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen, How can I load the data in a pipelined manner using Python library for Firebase? I am using this [link](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase) package.

Comment: Forgot to update, Got it done using Multiprocessing.Pool process of python over that Firebase Library